# Change signature of function called in __init__ of base class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

In `A.__init__` I call `self.func(argument)`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, argument, key=0):
        self.func(argument)
    def func(self, argument):
        #some code here
```

I want to change the signature of `A.func` in `B`. `B.func` gets called in `B.__init__` through `A.__init__`:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, argument1, argument2, key=0):
        super(B, self).__init__(argument1, key)  # calls A.__init__
    def func(self, argument1, argument2):
        #some code here
```

Clearly, this doesn't work because the signature of `B.func` expects two arguments while `A.__init__` calls it with one argument. How do I work around this? Or is there something incorrect with the way I have designed my classes?

`key` is a default argument to `A.__init__`. `argument2` is not intended for `key`. `argument2` is an extra argument that `B` takes but `A` does not. B also takes `key` and has default value for it.

Another constraint is that I would like not to change the signature of `A.__init__`. `key` will usually be `0`. So I want to allow users to be able to write `A(arg)` rather than `A(arg, key=0)`.

Comment: Why not provide a default value to `argument2`?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: judging by the super call, it's python2

Comment: @wim: or polyglot code, or someone not aware of the 0-argument form.

Comment: "In B, I want to change the signature of func" - sounds like you're breaking Liskov substitutability there. Are you sure this is a good idea? Also, calling methods from `__init__` that are meant to be overridden is dangerous, since those methods may depend on subclass initialization that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: There is some confusion among the answers, I think. Do you expect `argument1` and `argument2` to be passed on to `B.func()` when `super(B, self).__init__(argument1, argument2)` is called? What is the role of `key=0` in `A.__init__()` in this respect, should it capture the value of `argument2` *at all*?

Comment: I am writing this is python2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I do expect `argument1` and `argument2` to be passed to `B.func()` - but not necessarily when `super(B, self).__init__(argument1, argument2)` is called? I have changed the question to reflect role of `key`. It is a default parameter in both `A` & `B`.

Answer (score 6):

*Generally speaking*, changing the signature of a method between subclasses breaks the expectation that the methods on subclasses implement the same API as those on the parent.

However, you could re-tool your `A.__init__` to allow for arbitrary extra arguments, passing those on to `self.func()`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, argument, *extra, **kwargs):
        key = kwargs.get('key', 0)
        self.func(argument, *extra)
    # ...

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, argument1, argument2, key=0):
        super(B, self).__init__(argument1, argument2, key=key)
    # ...
```

The second argument passed to `super(B, self).__init__()` is then captured in the `extra` tuple, and applied to `self.func()` in addition to `argument`.

In Python 2, to make it possible to use `extra` however, you need to switch to using `**kwargs`, otherwise `key` is always going to capture the second positional argument. Make sure to pass on `key` from `B` with `key=key`.

In Python 3, you are not bound by this restriction; put `*args` before `key=0` and only ever use `key` as a keyword argument in calls:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, argument, *extra, key=0):
        self.func(argument, *extra)
```

I'd give `func()` an `*extra` parameter too, so that it's interface essentially is going to remain unchanged between `A` and `B`; it just ignores anything beyond the first parameter passed in for `A`, and beyond the first two for `B`:

```
class A(object):
    # ...
    def func(self, argument, *extra):
        # ...

class B(A):
    # ...
    def func(self, argument1, argument2, *extra):
        # ...
```

Python 2 demo:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, argument, *extra, **kwargs):
...         key = kwargs.get('key', 0)
...         self.func(argument, *extra)
...     def func(self, argument, *extra):
...         print('func({!r}, *{!r}) called'.format(argument, extra))
...
>>> class B(A):
...     def __init__(self, argument1, argument2, key=0):
...         super(B, self).__init__(argument1, argument2, key=key)
...     def func(self, argument1, argument2, *extra):
...         print('func({!r}, {!r}, *{!r}) called'.format(argument1, argument2, extra))
...
>>> A('foo')
func('foo', *()) called
<__main__.A object at 0x105f602d0>
>>> B('foo', 'bar')
func('foo', 'bar', *()) called
<__main__.B object at 0x105f4fa50>
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but it might be helpful to encourage different design practices. Could the first class use `super` to refer to the first classes implementation of the method?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower: not sure what you mean? `super(A, self).func(argument)` won't work, no, as search starts at the *next class* in the MRO.

Comment: @MartijnPieters A quick experiment led me to one solution to help the base class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that there is a problem in your design. The following might fix your particular case but seems to perpetuate bad design even further. Notice the `Parent.method` being called directly.

```
>>> class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a, b=None):
        Parent.method(self, a)
        self.b = b
    def method(self, a):
        self.location = id(a)


>>> class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super().__init__(a, object())
    def method(self, a, b):
        self.location = id(a), id(b)


>>> test = Child(object())
```

Please consider adding a default argument to the second parameter of the method you are overriding. Otherwise, design your class and call structure differently. Reorganization might eliminate the problem.

Comment: Now `Child.method()` is *never* called, and the extra argument `object()` is captured by `b`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My assumption may be incorrect, but it is that `Child.method` should not be called from `Parent.__init__`. Depending on the writer's intent, the `Child.method` may be designed to be called internally or externally in other places instead. If neither the parent or child methods should be called externally, renaming `method` to `__method` in both classes might be the way to go. Without further context, it is difficult to know what the best solution might be. There is even the option to rename it `_method` instead to indicate internal use. The proper answer is not obvious.

Comment: From the use of `argument1` and `argument2` as both local variables in `B.__init__` and as the names for `B.func()`, there is an implied expectation that `B.func()` is called from `A.__init__()`. I've commented on the question to get that clarified.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You are right. I intend to call `B.func()` when an object of class B is being initialized.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower: Could you say a bit more about why you think this is bad design?

My use case is that func creates an object that is related to the class. A kind of related table. This related object can be different - sometimes it has 2 tables instead of 1. I hope this clarifies my intention somewhat.

Comment: @Swetabh The problem may be eliminated by calling one or more internal methods from `__init__`. Then you can override whatever functionality you need in the child class. Such a design might also allow for not even needing to use super in the child class if there is only one or two lines of code to write. However, I agree with Martijn Pieters that supporting a variable number of arguments is probably the best way to go. Alternatively, you could just pass arrays/iterables to your function and require the caller to package the data in that fashion.

Answer (score 0):

actually I would resort to put an extra boolean argument in A's `__init__` to control the call of the func, and just pass **False** from B's `__init__`

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, argument, key=0, call_func=True):
        if call_func:
            self.func(argument)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, argument):
        argument1, argument2 = argument, 'something else'
        super(B, self).__init__(argument1, argument2, call_func=False)
```

Comment: So why override `func()` in `B` then? And you still capture `argument2` in `key`..

Comment: unaware of the usage of argument1, argument2 and key, I didn't try to make sense of the code, but, as far as I understood, that he needs to override func() in B but he had a problem that func() is being called as part of the A's init!

Comment: @0xcurb: I want to call `func` as it initializes an object I need to associate with `class A`. I would prefer not to rewrite the code inside `__init__` of A. In my case `A` also calls it's parent's constructor.